# Cannot play WMV files in Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-media-player, media-player, wmv

Currently at work I have a workstation with Windows Server 2003 R2 with SP2 and I cannot play WMV files. No, I wouldn't be slacking, we have internal webcasts that I need to view.

The Windows Media Player (version 10.00.00.3998) refuses to play the file stating

> An audio codec is needed to play this file. To determine if this codec is available to download from the Web, click Web Help.

I click the button and I am directed to [a page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/webhelp/default.aspx?ID=C00D10D1&codec=162) which instructs me to go to the [WMPlugins.com Web site](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=66220&codec=162).

I go there and I am told that [the audio codec is found](http://www.wmplugins.com/ItemDetail.aspx?&codec=162). Great.
After a few direct links I arrive at [a download page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/format/codecdownload.aspx) where I download the codec and install it. After the successfull install I am required to restart the computer.

Later trying to playback the file the same thing happens as in the beginning of this question.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[K lite codec](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm)** or **[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)** are the best in your situation

Comment: Well at least VLC plays the file although without sound... :(( It says that WMAP audio codec cannot be found and "there is no solution for this".

Answer (score 1):

My best recommendation is to install one of the Free codec packs listed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/5184/best-free-codec-pack). They generally include all required codecs for your system.

Comment: Installed it, still no go... I guess there must be something broken with my Windows installation.